# Could not view with composite pK CakePHP4

Tags: cakephp, composite-primary-key, cakephp-4.x

In [cakephp-4.x](/questions/tagged/cakephp-4.x) I could not access Controller's view action for composite primary key table. (http://localhost:8765/invoice-items/view/1)

[image]

Here are samples of the code created by `cake bake`:

**InvoiceItemsTable calss** in which the primary key is defined as composite.

```php
class InvoiceItemsTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('invoice_items');
        $this->setDisplayField(['item_id', 'invoice_id', 'unit_id']);
        $this->setPrimaryKey(['item_id', 'invoice_id', 'unit_id']);

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Items', [
            'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Invoices', [
            'foreignKey' => 'invoice_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Units', [
            'foreignKey' => 'unit_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    }
...
```

**InvoiceItemsController view method**:

```php
/**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Invoice Item id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $invoiceItem = $this->InvoiceItems->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Items', 'Invoices', 'Units'],
        ]);

        $this->set(compact('invoiceItem'));
    }
```

Finally a screen shot of `invoice_items` table structure from phpmyadmin:

[image]

I have tried to access the view like (http://localhost:8765/invoice-items/view/1,1,6) but I got the same error `... with primary key ['1,1,6'].` I do not know how to **represent the composite primary key in the URL**? or what is the problem?

I use CakePHP version 4.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table::get()` expects composite keys to be passed as arrays, eg `[1, 1, 6]`.

Assuming you're using the fallback routes from the default app skeleton, you can pass additional arguments as path parts, eg:

```
/invoice-items/view/1/1/6
```

and accept them in your controller action like:

```php
public function view($itemId, $invoiceId, $unitId)
```

and build an array from the accordingly to pass to `get()` as the "id":

```php
$this->InvoiceItems->get([$itemId, $invoiceId, $unitId], /* ... */)
```

In case you're using custom routes with fixed parameters, add additional ones in whatever form you like, for example with dashes:

```php
$routes
    ->connect(
        '/invoice-items/view/{itemId}-{invoiceId}-{unitId}',
        ['controller' => 'InvoiceItems', 'action' => 'view']
    )
    ->setPass(['itemId', 'invoiceId', 'unitId'])
    ->setPatterns([
        'itemId' => '\d+',
        'invoiceId' => '\d+',
        'unitId' => '\d+',
    ]);
```

then your URL would look like:

```
/invoice-items/view/1-1-6
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Route Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#route-elements)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > Passing Parameters to Action](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action)**
- **[Cookbook > Routing > Fallbacks Method](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#fallbacks-method)**

Comment: I don't use custom routes. The parameters are url encoded like `1%2F1%2F6` it works but I just need them to be `1/1/6` without encoding.